# merging sublists within a list sharing common index element

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list like:

```
loc_list=[['1,', "'Houston'"], 
         ['4,', "'Stafford'"], 
         ['5,', "'Bellaire'"], 
         ['5,', "'Sugarland'"], 
         ['5,', "'Houston'"], 
         ['6,', "'Atlanta'"], 
         ['6,', "'Sacramento'"], 
         ['7,', "'Milwaukee'"], 
         ['8,', "'Chicago'"], 
         ['8,', "'Dallas'"], 
         ['8,', "'Philadephia'"], 
         ['8,', "'Seattle'"], 
         ['8,', "'Miami'"], 
         ['9,', "'Arlington'"], 
         ['11,', "'Austin'"]]
```

Now I want to merge the list having same element at first position.

```
Desired_list=[['1,', "'Houston'"], 
             ['4,', "'Stafford'"], 
             ['5,', "'Bellaire','Sugarland','Houston'"],
             ['6,', "'Atlanta','Sacramento'"],
             ['7,', "'Milwaukee'"], 
             ['8,', "'Chicago','Dallas','Philadephia','Seattle','Miami'"], 
             ['9,', "'Arlington'"], 
             ['11,', "'Austin'"]]
```

I'm clueless.

Comment: Why don't you use a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be better off with a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)-like structure, [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) would seem the best choice.

Here's an example:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(set)
>>> for index,city in loc_list:
...   d[index].add(city)
... 
>>> for k,v in d.items():
...   print(k,v)
... 
4, {"'Stafford'"}
6, {"'Atlanta'", "'Sacramento'"}
1, {"'Houston'"}
5, {"'Houston'", "'Bellaire'", "'Sugarland'"}
9, {"'Arlington'"}
8, {"'Philadephia'", "'Dallas'", "'Seattle'", "'Chicago'", "'Miami'"}
7, {"'Milwaukee'"}
11, {"'Austin'"}
```

BTW: Your input list looks a bit strange, the *keys* are strings (instead of numbers) with a trailing coma: `'4,'`; and the *values* have double quotes: `"'Chicago'"`.

Comment: will be stripping these now. thanks for the suggestion. Actually loading directly from CSV so that's why...

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that:

```
desired_list = {}
for elem in loc_list:
  if not elem[0] in desired_list:
    desired_list[elem[0]] = []
  desired_list[elem[0]].append(elem[1])


print desired_list
```

It's not a list but a dictionary
The output is:

```
{'9,': ["'Arlington'"], '8,': ["'Chicago'", "'Dallas'", "'Philadephia'", "'Seattle'", "'Miami'"], '11,': ["'Austin'"], '7,': ["'Milwaukee'"], '6,': ["'Atlanta'", "'Sacramento'"], '5,': ["'Bellaire'", "'Sugarland'", "'Houston'"], '4,': ["'Stafford'"], '1,': ["'Houston'"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate your concerns.
Depending on your index range just take something like an array or a hashtable.

Then for each item, you can have a set, and depending on your desires, you could have multiplicity in your set or not.

For initial construction you will need to traverse the list.

Answer (score 0):

I've written this solution that I think it's very clear and efficient. 
Using a defaultdict (data type from the collections package) you can obtain the same result with a little effort:

```
import collections as co

loc_list=[['1,', "'Houston'"], 
         ['4,', "'Stafford'"], 
         ['5,', "'Bellaire'"], 
         ['5,', "'Sugarland'"], 
         ['5,', "'Houston'"], 
         ['6,', "'Atlanta'"], 
         ['6,', "'Sacramento'"], 
         ['7,', "'Milwaukee'"], 
         ['8,', "'Chicago'"], 
         ['8,', "'Dallas'"], 
         ['8,', "'Philadephia'"], 
         ['8,', "'Seattle'"], 
         ['8,', "'Miami'"], 
         ['9,', "'Arlington'"], 
         ['11,', "'Austin'"]]


def transform_list():
    count = co.defaultdict(list)

    for sublist in loc_list:
        count[sublist[0]].append(sublist[1])

    return count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = transform_list()
    print(count)
```

Passing a list to the defaultdict constructor your able to automatically create an empty list when a new key is specified.
I suggest to you to consider this example: [defaultdict examples](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples)